# What is the best way to call a .net webservice using jquery?

Tags: .net, jquery, web-services

I'd like to call a .net webservice from another domain using only jquery.

What is the best way to do this? and are there any configuration changes I need to be aware of on the web site hosting the web page?

The reason I ask this, is that I am only marginally in control of that area. 
So I can only make limited changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is to make the crossdomain call. You have to change the data type of your jQuery request to `jsonp`.

Take a look at this [link](http://elegantcode.com/2008/12/02/calling-remote-aspnet-web-services-from-jquery/)

Comment: +1, may need changes that the asker can't make, but will work cross-domain

Answer (score 3):

The browser does not allow XMLHTTPRequest calls across domains in its default configuration. You can change browser settings to make certain calls succeed, but this is considered bad practice.

In order to perform cross-domain requests, you can

- [Use the local server as a proxy to
  a remote server](http://dotnetslackers.com/columns/ajax/MashitUpwithASPNETAJAX.aspx)

  This example uses a local ASP.NET Web Service to make a call to the Yahoo! Geocode service
- [Use a bridge](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/FlickrSpell.aspx)

  This example demonstrates how to create a bridge to [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) through the flickr API.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the answer is no, assuming you are talking about ASPX Web Services (basically a WebService hosted in an ASP.NET site).

This is the first hit on Google when searching for "webservice call jquery" which should give you more info:

http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/
you are using to host the web service).

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not really sure if cross-site ajax as implemented in jquery will work in all browsers (firefox 3) just like that.
Second, I assume you are talking about a SOAP web service. I'd rather not do that. It'll be very complicated to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$.post("CodersWS.asmx/DeleteBook", { id_book: parseInt(currBookID, 10) }, function(res) {
///do something with returned data: res
});
```

In the above example, I am calling a web service named `CodersWS.asmx`, and the WebMethod inside it called `DeleteBook`...I am also passing a parameter called `id_book`.

Also don't forget to add this snippet to your `web.config`, or else you wouldn't be able to access the web-service this way:

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Is that the client's web.config or the webservices?

Answer (score 0):

Would a better approach be to use:
Jquery.getJSON?

See:
[JQuery.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback)

This raises the question of how to output JSON compliant data using a webservice or similiar mechanism.

Comment: Use the [ScriptService] attribute on the webservice to allow it to be called from client side script. The default will return JSON - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx

Comment: Used in conjunction with JQuery's $.ajax({}); command in a similar fashion to call a webservice such as here - http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ should do what you require