# How to call external webservice using jquery "jsonp"?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, web-services

I had a previous question [can jquery ajax call external webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727183/can-jquery-ajax-call-external-webservice)

and some good developers answered me to use jsonp, but i don't know how to use it, i am trying to call my service using this code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:1096/MySite/WebService.asmx?callback=?",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(msg) {alert(msg);}
            });
```

and this is my service code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World " ;
}
```

anyone have examples or can explain this issue for me?

**UPDATE**:
I wrote the code again to be like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:1096/YourShoppingTest1/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld?jsonp=?",{name:"test"},
    function(data){
    alert(data.x);
    });
```

and the service like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(string name)
{
    return "( {\"x\":10 , \"y\":100} )";
}
```

But it always give me this error when back: "missing ; before statement
[Break on this error] ( {"x":10 , "y":100} )"

and never call the success function, can anyone help with that?

Comment: Why have you accepted the answer to your other question if it didn't help you? You should keep asking in your old question and follow that thread.

Comment: because they answered me with this way: $.getJSON which is working, but i am asking about another way using $.ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similiar problem, unfortunately I don't have the code at hand.

From memory:

- Add [ScriptService] as an attribute to your Web Method
- Also change your url to call the HelloWorld procedure.
  Something like http://localhost:1096/MySite/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld?callback

See: [What are some good examples of JQuery using JSONP talking to .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448879/what-are-some-good-examples-of-jquery-using-jsonp-talking-to-net) & [What is the best way to call a .net webservice using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426420/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-net-webservice-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

The point with JSONP is the P! P as in padding. You are padding the JSON object literal with a function call - invoking a function on the calling page taking the data object as an argument.

I.e. if you request the webservice, send the desired callback function name in the query string

```
...service/?callback=hello
```

Then the service should answer (using appropriate mime type):

```
hello({a: 17, b: 4117});
```

For a more in-depth explanation, see:
http://www.stpe.se/2008/10/cross-site-data-retrieval-using-jsonp/

Answer (score 0):

You can't issue a POST request using JSONP, only GET (because `<script src="...">`  GETs the resource).

Answer (score 0):

Hezil's code worked for me, but I had to change the server code to this:

```
$data = '{"name" : "hello world"}'; echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
```

Note the "callback" instead of "jsoncallback".

Answer (score -1):

First you should add jsonp ('callback') in your web  server   like $_GET['callback']

Second ,don't forget the ';' after the output scripts

```
$data = '{"name" : "hello world"}';
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
```

Now you can find out why the "missing ; before statement" problem occured.

html:

```
$.getJSON({"http://localhost:1096/MySite/WebService.asmx?callback=?",
        function(data){alert(data);}
        });
```